# Content Scrolls Below Header

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index, positioning

I wanted to have my header fixed at the top of every page so I added the following rules...

```
header {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Now my problem is that the rest of the pages is clipped by the header. Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add a `margin-top` to your content div which should be equal to the height of the header. For example, if this is your structure:

```
<header></header>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

and your header has a height of `200px`, you should add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
#wrapper {
     margin-top: 200px;
}
```